# How to get the html title(header) with SimpleHTMLDom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I've used the simple_html_dom to get the a page title in head tag...I've search the solutions 
for my implemention...Could you give me some insparition..
any method to help me?

thanks..

Answer (score 4):

The [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) is pretty clear, anyway you could achieve with this code:

Given the tag `<title>IANA &mdash; Example domains</title>` you can use

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url = 'http://www.example.com';

$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file($url);
$title = $html->find('title',0);
echo $title->plaintext;

//output : IANA — Example domains
```

Plaintext will give you the content stripped of all html tags, so just...plain text. If you want the innerHtml you can use `$title->innertext;` instead (in this case it doesn't make any difference, but will if you have html tags within the tag you're going to fetch)

Comment: The code I provided is fully working, you can paste it as is and gives you the <title> attribute of the site 'www.example.com', which indeed exists :)

Comment: yes ,It does work .. Moreover , I have achieve my expection..

What I wasn't aware of was the second argument in find method ..I've lost it..

Comment: @Jason Well, maybe the manual isn't really verbose about this things, after all. If this solution works you can mark it as accepted, for future references. Thank you!